# How can I create a layout like this?

Tags: android, android-layout

Two tiles SORT and REMINDER and having Sub Item as shown in image.
I have tried this by using Listview but nothing made up like this.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is easy with Shared Preferences, take a look at [this](http://androidresearch.wordpress.com/2012/03/09/creating-a-preference-activity-in-android/) tutorial

In brief: for all Preference Category you have the possibility to add a title, in your case SORT and REMINDER.

Comment: Thanks this tutorial helps a lot >>Ofir

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [**PreferenceCategory**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceCategory.html) to acheive this.

The **Settings** screen usually makes use of the [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) and you could use a PreferenceActivity to do it or you can handle all the interaction manually.

The preference category helps you to categorize all the preference settings into various groups, so as to make it easy for the user to understand which setting is for which functionality.

An excerpt from the documentation :

> Used to group Preference objects and provide a disabled title above
>   the group.

Comment: Swayam >>can you provide me a better example?

Comment: You can find loads like: http://www.example8.com/category/view/id/15750 and http://alvinalexander.com/java/jwarehouse/android/core/java/android/preference/PreferenceCategory.java.shtml

Comment: @swayam it's a little funny to give an example from my answer, don't you think?

Comment: @OfirA. : Hey hey hey! I just did a google search and pasted the first few links. Cant help if one of them turns out to be a part of your answer. I will remove it, if you want. :)

Comment: @swayam No hard feelings, it's OK.

Comment: @OfirA. : None here either. I removed the link anyway. :)

Comment: swayam>>Please dont mind but the link you provide is already provided by @Ofir.

Comment: Like I said, I just did a Google search. https://www.google.co.in/search?q=android+preference+category+example and it happens to be the very first link. Please don't blame me for plagiarism. :P